# Почему парсинг времени в Boost не проверяет диапазоны?

Tags: c++, парсер, время, boost

Почему функция [`parse_delimeted_time`](https://github.com/boostorg/date_time/blob/develop/include/boost/date_time/time_parsing.hpp#L180), используемая, в частности, при парсинге строки дата-время не учитывает ограничения для компонентов? Например, сжирает такое:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как отдельную строку времени можно объяснить отсутствие проверки для старших "разрядов", например, кол-ва часов в приведённом примере. Но почему нет такой проверки в составе комплексной строки с наличием даты или когда есть часы, а минуты и секунды при этом превышают 59?

Comment: не понятно в контексте duration в чём сакральная разница между `1200:00:00` и `00:00:1200`

Comment: @nörbörnën какого duration? Где кол-во секунд в минуте может быть несколько тысяч?

Comment: А почему бы, в сущности, и не парсить расширенные строковые представления? Например, в южной Корее указывают время окончания сеансов, и для вечерних это вполне могут быть строки вида "25:40". В сутках 24 часа? Нет, не слышали) Главное, чтобы после парсера значение было корректным

Comment: @PakUula ничего себе вечерочек затянулся. Похоже на "пока я не лег спать, день не закончится". С таким парсингом возникает проблема двусторонних преобразований: обратно уже "25:40" не получить, а будет "01:40".